# Как работает оператор [] в std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, типы-данных, smart-pointer

Пытаюсь получить доступ к элементу массива через его указатель, объявленный как `shared_ptr` так:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    {
        shared_ptr<int> up(new int[5] {1,2,3,4,5});
        cout << up[3];
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Однако во время компиляции выдаётся ошибка о том, что "отсутствует оператор `[]`, соответствующий этим операндам".

Я прочитал на [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_at) и в подсказка среды разработки, что оператор `[]` у `shared_ptr` принимает тип `ptrdiff_t`, однако так:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    {
        shared_ptr<int> up(new int[5] {1,2,3,4,5});
        cout << up[static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(3)];
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

тоже не работает с той же ошибкой.

Вопрос: как всё-таки правильно пользоваться этим оператором и что я делаю не так?

Comment: `shared_ptr<int[]>`

Comment: @int3 Вау. Большое спасибо. Быстро и просто. Вынесите в ответ, если хотите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая Ваша ошибка - попытка инициализировать `std::shared_ptr<int>` массивом, выделенным через `new int[]`. Это некорректно, так как `shared_ptr<T>` вызывает `delete` при освобождении памяти, а не требуемый `delete[]`.

Замена `int` на `int[]` решает эту проблему и Вашу - умный указатель понимает, что на самом деле содержит в себе массив и позволяет его индексировать.